# MassTransit - non-scoped publish fiters

Tags: c#, .net-core, masstransit

I have created a Masstransit publish filter, that creates a message header, based on information provided by an accessor.

I want to set some values in the accessor, during processing, which will be picked up by the publish filter.

The way I understand filters, is that they are scoped, and therefore, any message published, will create a new DI scope.  This means that the values I set before publishing the message, will not be available in the filter.

```
public interface IAccessor
{
   Guid Id {get;set;}
}

public class Accessor : IAccessor
{
   public Guid Id {get;set;}
}

public class MyPublishFilter<T> : IFilter<PublishContext<T>> where T : class 
{
    private readonly IAccessor accessor;
    public MyPublishFilter(IAccessor accessor) 
     => this.accessor = accessor; <-- this accessor is different to the one in MyProgram
    public async Task Send(PublishContext<T> context, IPipe<PublishContext<T>> next) 
    { 
        context.CorrelationId = accessor.Id; 
        await next.Send(context);
    }

public class MyProgram
{
    public MyProgram(IAccessor accessor) => this.accessor = accessor;
    public async Task DoThing()
    {
        accessor.Id = Guid.NewGuid();  <--- this value is not passed to the filter
        messageBus.Publish(new Message());
    }

}
```

Is there a way to tell MassTransit NOT to create a new scope for message filters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use an existing scope, use `IPublishEndpoint` instead of `IBus` to publish the message. You should resolve `IPublishEndpoint` from the container scope service provider, and the scoped filter should use the same scope.

```cs
await using var scope = provider.CreateScope();

// use the scope to set your accessor Id

var publishEndpoint = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IPublishEndpoint>();

await publishEndpoint.Publish(...);
```